# Updating different tab with a script from a pivot table????

Tags: google-apps-script

I am new to coding scripts in google and come into a problem I can not work through and my script "mentor" is still not that experienced and can't figure it out either.

I am trying to update a different tab on my sheet from a pivot table when I use my script to send out bulked emails.

So the link below will bring you to the dummy sheet built off my real sheet. The 'PM' tab column L is what I am trying to update. It starts at 1 on all jobs. The emails are sent out by the Blue button on the next tab 'Follow up email' (this is just a pivot table so I can always adjust who is getting the emails easily). But I cant figure out how to have it update the 'PM' tab with the button at the same time as the emails go out.

Link to the open shared spreadsheet. Feel free to play around if you can help.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_hipIj4suI2xMGUrZhMTBDvkQv9Y9O3JRNNQUpSeAP0/edit?usp=sharing

(only got the emails to  send properly so far)

```
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
  var rows = sheet.getLastRow()
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1, rows-1, 7);
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[1]; // Second column
    var message = 'Hello, we have submitted this job ' + row[2] + ' days Ago. ' + row[4] + ' \n\n' + ' -' + row[5]; 
    var subject = row[0]; // First column
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }
}
```

I need the button to send out emails on the 'Follow up email' tab and at the same time "email counter" (column L) would get 1 added to it on the 'PM' Tab. This way I can keep track of how many times that job was emailed from the sheet.

Comment: Which row gets the counter updated? the one with the email address that gets sent the email?

Comment: yes, the line the pivot table is pulling off of would get the update

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
function sendEmails() {
  var pmSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("PM");
  var emailSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Follow up email");

  var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
  var rows = emailSheet.getLastRow()
  var dataRange = emailSheet.getRange(2, 1, rows-1, 7);
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[1]; // Second column
    var message = 'Hello, we have submitted this job ' + row[2] + ' days Ago. ' + row[4] + ' \n\n' + ' -' + row[5]; 
    var subject = row[0]; // First column
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
    updatePM(pmSheet, emailAddress);
  }
}

function updatePM(sheet, email){
  var value;
  var emails = sheet.getRange("G3:G" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < emails.length; i++)
    if (emails[i][0] == email){
      value = sheet.getRange("K" + (i+3)).getValue() + 1
      sheet.getRange("K" + (i+3)).setValue(value);
    }
}
```

I changed the way you got the sheets just to be safe, then I just wrote a small function that gets called after the email is sent, which checks the list of emails in the PM sheet and then updates the value in the sent email column.

Comment: I tried it, it tells me "Cannot call method "getRange" of undefined"  Tried to make a few changes to fix it but it wouldn't work.

Comment: Sorry the original error was "Range not found" , after my changes it said "Cannot call method "getRange" of undefined".

Comment: I put a picture on the bottom of the PM tab of the debugging, now its saying line 21. I don't know what is going on or why it changed lines now.

Comment: That's odd, please provide edit access to the sheet, otherwise I cannot go into the code

Comment: @JohnVelella I updated the code in my answer and in the sheet you shared, it was working as intended when I tested it. The range was wrong because my previous code was not accounting for the headers.